# Primitive class field variable written / read by different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got the following class as part of a project I've taken on (rewritten / renamed to simplify example):

```
public class Temp {
    private boolean bool = false;

    // edit 1: calibrate called by other threads in the program
    public void calibrate() {
        bool = true;
    }

    public Temp() {
       thread.start(); 
    }

    private final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(bool) {
                    // do some different work
                    bool = false;
                }
                else {
                    // do regular work
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The code essentially provides the calibrate method do change the work that the thread is doing temporarily. However, this uses a primitive boolean which surprises me as both threads write to the variable.

Shouldn't this need some kind of synchronization? I think it should but it works correctly as is somehow. If it doesn't need synchronization, why?

Edit 2: This isn't my code, someone else made this - I'm fixing it! :)

Comment: Where is the other thread?

Comment: Starting threads inside constructors? I would advice not to do so... Even if in this particular case it's harmless...

Comment: Surely you need synchronization. As tons of topics before explained, without synchronization anything can happens.

Comment: If you create multiple instances of Temp class they actually have separate instances of that bool variable. maybe that's why it works

Comment: Thread race conditions rarely happen when you want them to. They follow Murphy's Law to the letter and prefer to show up in production (especially under heavy load). They are unpredictable that way.

Comment: If you have concurrent access and modification e.g. of a `bool` you should better use [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) to avoid most of the problems.

Comment: Cheers everyone for the advice! I don't have any issues with implementing the synchronization / use of Java's concurrent packages, I'm just astounded as to why the example works

Comment: @St.Antario Only started the thread in constructor as I that's what the current code is doing, I know it's not good practice and plan to change that but had to sort out why it is working with primitives on multiple threads first :)

Comment: @user7 the calibrate function is called by other threads in the program, I'll add an edit :)

Answer (score 4):

**It might be working for now, but it doesn't makes it right.**

Primitive data types are just not thread safe, and nothing can justify it. And that's why JDK gives you `Atomic` classes as wrapper for thread safety with primitive data types. I would replace the `bool` with `AtomicBoolean` without any doubt, otherwise given code is meant to fail.

Check out this [blog](http://i-proving.com/2009/04/23/java-primitive-thread-safety/?showComments=true) showing inconsistent test results with primitives used in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: OT: You might wanna revise your stackoverflow title :)

Comment: That was a catch :).

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to say whether the code is correct without knowing more about the context of what is happening.

Is it OK if the boolean is true, the first thread goes in the first block, and in the middle of it another thread changes it to false? Do you want to allow two threads to go in the first block, even though one of them is going to change it to false while the other is still running in the `true` block? In that case you need to have more synchronization constructs around the block itself, not just a simple boolean check.

With regards to synchronization on primitives, one thing you should definitely do is declare it as `private volatile boolean bool = false;` This ensures that each thread does not keep a locally cached copy of the variable whose value could become outdated.

You also have the option to use `AtomicBoolean` if you want to have thread safe updating of the variable itself, but I suspect this is the least of your thread safety issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Safety or liveness** failure rarely happen but when it does, it's always when it's heavily loaded in production.

Recently I am trying to experiment some **race conditions** to present the necessity of introducing **synchronized** block properly. But most of the time, I have to design it with great caution to make it re-occur.

There are several issues in your demo you have to fix as to **synchronization**.

As @St.Antario points out, you'd better **NOT** start the thread in the **constructor**, when it's extended (as a parent class), it can be dangerous that the thread will access some methods overridden in child class while the child class is still not yet initialized completely.

Answer (score 0):

By your comment

> other threads call the calibrate() method

there can be a semantical problem caused by concurrency issues.

What happens when the inner thread resets the boolean varaible to false,and at the same time, or in close period, an outer thread updates `bool` variable to true before the `if` statement is concluded. You would expect to do `regular work` but instead, you will be doing `some different work` because the outer thread changed the value back to `true` before the `while` condition was rechecked.